# Using Rails + Devise, how can I "manually" validate a session cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I've got a Rails (3.2.5) app using Devise (2.1.2) for auth.

Suppose I have this session cookie:

```
session_cookie = {
  "session_id"           => "{SESSION_ID}",
  "_csrf_token"          => "{CSRF_TOKEN}",
  "warden.user.user.key" => ["User", [{USER_ID}], "{ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD}"]
}
```

Is there a way I can "manually" validate it, i.e., ensure it's not a forgery by directly calling a method on Devise or Warden? I'm imagining something like this: `Devise::SomeModule.is_session_cookie_valid?(session_cookie)`, but in looking in the gems' code, haven't found anything that seems to do this.

If the information in `session_cookie` isn't sufficient, what else would I need?